# Tags don't want to play with s

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, tags, unicode

[tag:]

As can readily be seen, tags seem to discriminate against bananas and don't want to play with them. I thought SO was a place of no discrimination against other origins, but it seems the ASCII-Landers are considered first-class citizens, while the Unicodians are seated below them. The same behaviour can be seen in the chat. Here's an evidence photo:

[image]
<sup>(Properly censored, of course.)</sup>

I don't think SO should tolerate this behaviour and reeducate the tags. This might be especially problematic on some of the language sites, like French Language & Usage.

Comment: getting ready for April 1st?

Comment: @Abyx this is serious, you don't use discriminate unicode.

Comment: They're already working on internationalization features (see http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/23539/stack-overflow-in-portuguese for ex.). I'm not sure bananas are included in the plan though.

Comment: This is absulutely serious in my opinion. Either you support Unicode or not. If you don't, prepare for being accused of being middle-ages mind :D

Comment: @lechlukasz - but it would _look_ a  lot more serious with another sample. Anything but a banana.

Comment: @HenkHolterman: ok, try with a  then.

Comment: I should add that even if you account for normalization and casing, you will miss things like `sœur`, `soeur`, `SŒUR`, `SOEUR`, `ꜱɶᴜʀ`, and `ꜱᴏᴇᴜʀ` needing to all match one another. If you use the primary-stength–only UCA comparison, however, they shall. D[oing Unicode right](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6162484/why-does-modern-perl-avoid-utf-8-by-default/6163129#6163129) is considerably harder than most people realize.

Comment: Guys what are you all talking about? All I see are blank squares! No banana and no shoes.

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd ![SVG](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/1f34c/banana.svg)

Comment: @Back peeled banana!

Comment: I, like @ShaWizDowArd, only see boxes.  Strange that Android sees the monkies and bananas fine, but I do not... :(

Comment: @Makoto 1. Chrome doesn't have font fallback; try a different browser. 2. A browser with font fallback still needs a font with those glyphs somewhere; try updating your system to get newer fonts. 3. Just assume any blank squares are bananas.

Comment: What's with all the unicode weirdness?  Most people can't even see them!

Comment: @Seth "all the unicode weirdness" is only as weird as what *people* use to communicate in writing.

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes True enough..

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes There are browsers without font fallbacks? Really? Isn’t that a bug?

Comment: @tchrist I kind of glossed the issue there. It does have some sort of thing they call font fallback. But it has a slew of reported bugs that make it seem almost as if it did not. And it seems most issues show up only on the Windows version.

Comment: This is the C++ Lounge, isn't it?

Answer (score 19):

[image: picture of − ( ) = ⃠]

Focussing on bananas and related monkey-business serves only to distract from the real issue here, which is that tags are restricted to only a few possible characters, the letters and digits from old-school 7-bit ASCII.

Bananas are symbols, not alphanumerics, and tags are a sort of identifier. So it makes reasonable sense to restrict tags to identifier characters.

It does not make sense to restrict those identifier characters to the ASCII range only.  It is, however, somewhat justifiable, in that as soon as you allow for non-ASCII alphanumerics, all kinds of tricky issues arise.  Here’s a brief sampling of things people might care to choose from:

[image: Unicode samples]

It is perfectly reasonable to hope to use non-ASCII alphanumerics. In practice, however, it becomes [much trickier to get right](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6162484/why-does-modern-perl-avoid-utf-8-by-default/6163129#6163129) than most people ever imagine.  There are both technical and stylistic considerations that have to be dealt with first.

As I previously wrote in comments, it doesn’t take symbols to show the problem. You can use straight alphabetics.

Try making a tag like `café`, `naïveté`, `jalapeños`, `tschüß`. Now realize that you must also account for differences in casing (`CAFÉ`, `NAÏVETÉ`, `JALAPEÑOS`, `TSCHÜSS`) and normalization (unnormalized, normalization form C, normalization form D, etc), and you will see that this is seriously trickier than if it’s limited to the (cave-)manly ASCII alphabet. Probably it is best to compare the strings using an untailored primary-strength–only UCA comparision, which counts only letters not diacritics or case.

Maybe.   You might want to tailor for language-based locales; for example, on [German L&U](https://german.stackexchange.com/), you would want to equate *tschüß* and *tschueß*, which is not the normal rule.

Also, even if you account for normalization and casing, you will miss things like `sœur`, `soeur`, `SŒUR`, `SOEUR`, `ꜱɶᴜʀ`, and `ꜱᴏᴇᴜʀ` needing to all match one another. If you use the primary-stength–only UCA comparison, however, they shall. Doing Unicode right really is considerably harder than most people realize.

## Sisyphean Tasks

Finally, StackExchange is, for the most part at least, currently written in the Latin and Common scripts.  The examples I have given so far are all in one of those two scripts. There may be sites where Greek or Arabic or what not are commonly used.  Arabic is a problem because of bidirectional issues, but English text has traditionally allowed for Greek characters in it, and even that poses trickinesses.

Suppose someone wants to use `ΣΊΣΥΦΟΣ` or `Σίσυφος` as a tag. Default casing rules would cause the first one to be lowercased to `σίσυφοσ` instead of to `σίσυφος`, which is its own problem.

If you say that StackExchange sites are all English-only, except perhaps for the various non-English Language & Usage sites, then perhaps you will allow only English words, or at least, English-looking words.  Not counting [the various letters used by Old English or Middle English like thorn and ash and wynn](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/58470/ye-olde-english-alphabet-question-any-other-letters-lost-besides-thorn-edh-an/58489#58489), you still have lot to choose from, even in Modern English. The *Oxford English Dictionary* has entries for all of these terms in it, including the ones with Greek in them:

[image: OED Unicode examples]

So we can’t even use arbitrary English words, not just Old English words like *wrǽððu*  or *wrǽþþu*, but Modern English words like the ones in the table above. That seems . . . unfortunate.

---

**NOTE**: I have for the most part used embedded images here instead of the literal code points, because I’m tired of people who read StackOverflow on their Dick-Tracy smart-watches complaining of wee boxes.  All images used by the kind permission of the author.

Answer (score 9):

Unicode support is enabled on a per-site basis.  The language sites that need it have it turned on already, it is not enabled on Stack Overflow.

We haven't seen a large need for them there with nearly 5 million questions asked...to change the tag rules and introduce them at this point we'd have to see a very convincing argument.

Comment:  should be a good enough argument.

Comment: Is it Friday again already?

Comment: This is clearly a bug, not a missing feature, at least in chat. It's the UTF-16 curse again. Or maybe the UCS-2 curse from JavaScript. I don't know which part of the code handles this. In chat, characters like ç or á can be used just fine in tags. The trouble comes up with non-BMP characters like . A tag with **one** of these characters ends up as **two** question marks. Not even replacement characters, but question marks. I challenge the notion that that was designed.

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes - While I agree it should be supported for **chat.stackexchange.com**  which hosts chat for sites with tags that have unicode characters(and we'll look at that), I don't consider it a bug on chat.stackoverflow.com.  On Stack Overflow these are invalid tags to begin with.

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes Pretty sure that *ever* rendering single code points as a ***pair*** of question-mark oopsy-doopsy glyphs is a guaranteed UCS-2 (or mishandled UTF-16) bug. Seems to happen a lot here.

Comment: “The language sites that need it have it turned on already”. Oh? On [french.se], it's technically possible to edit accented letters into tags, [but this messes up the database](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/224158/database-inconsistencies-after-tag-merge-operations-involving-non-ascii-characte), it seems to still use `é` and `à` as tag name separators (which is unfortunate as `é` is the most common accented letter in tag names in French).

Comment: @Gilles those separators are no longer used in the database, you can read a detailed post about it here: http://marcgravell.blogspot.co.uk/2014/04/technical-debt-case-study-tags.html

Comment: Nice! So are http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/224158/database-inconsistencies-after-tag-merge-operations-involving-non-ascii-characte and http://meta.french.stackexchange.com/questions/105/not-possible-to-have-accents-in-tags [meta-tag:status-completed]? What should we do with the questions with broken tagging due to attempts at introducing *étiquettes*?

Comment: @Gilles I'm not sure on the status for the bad data introduced from the admin tools - I'll relay to Marc who's heading up the changes there and he'll give it love tomorrow or Tuesday, we can very likely do some automated cleanup there

Comment: Any word from Marc? Should we wait 6–8 weeks?